# Customize Spring Boot executable-jar startup script

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, executable-jar, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I'm trying to run Spring Boot executable-jar built using spring-boot-maven-plugin on a Linux machine. The machine has multiple jdks installed, the one on PATH is jdk8 and changing it is unfortunately not an option. My executable-jar however needs jdk17, so when I just launch it as is I get `UnsupportedClassVersionError`.

I was following [the official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-script-customization-conf-file) and created the corresponding .conf file to override JAVA_HOME. But this does not seem to solve the issue:

```
[root@ios-maket updater-new]# ls
updater-new-3.0-SNAPSHOT.conf  updater-new-3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[root@ios-maket updater-new]# cat updater-new-3.0-SNAPSHOT.conf
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-17/bin/java
[root@ios-maket updater-new]# ./updater-new-3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Application is running as root (UID 0). This is considered insecure.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError...
```

On the other hand if I run it manually everything works fine:

```
[root@ios-maket updater-new]# /opt/jdk-17/bin/java -jar ./updater-new-3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[main] INFO com.icl.ios.fias.updaternew.UpdaterNew - Starting UpdaterNew using Java 17.0.6
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `JAVA_HOME` is not enough, you also need to set `PATH` to point to `JAVA_HOME/bin`.

```
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-17
PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
java -jar updater-new-3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer pointed me in the right direction. If `JAVA_HOME` is specified in .conf file - SpringBoot init script will handle the PATH. So what I needed was to change `JAVA_HOME` to `/opt/jdk-17`. Now the app launches with command `./updater-new-3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Try running the jar with -Dloader.path to specify the config manually.

```
java -Dloader.path=./updater-new-3.0-SNAPSHOT.conf -jar ./updater-new-3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

If this still does not work, then probably there is an issue with your config file, but from what I can see, your config file looks okay, unless the java path is incorrect.